# PDF viewer that supports Regex search

Tags: windows, gratis, regex, portable, pdf-viewer

I am looking for a PDF viewer with the following features:

- Supports Regex search, preferably Perl compatible
- Runs on Windows (7 and up)
- Is portable, or can be made portable
- Gratis

Nice to have:

- Ability to scan through mulitple files or directories

Comment: Can you provide an example of the type of search you might be performing that requires regex?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard  Yes. For example, if I want to look through the [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) to remind myself how to mark a path with an arrow, it's much faster to search for `/mark.+arrow/` than even reading through the table of contents to find the corresponding subheading. Some pdf handbooks even lack an indexed table of contents

Comment: Great example!  Very useful.